# get_url error in playbook, downloading a file from webserver

Tags: ansible

Iam trying to download a tar file from webserver, hosted in

```
/var/www/html/repo.example.com
```

directory in node2. I have web.yml playbook to do it, but when i execute it, i get following verbose message culminating in Request failed, urlopen error Name or service not known . Can any one help 
me, understand why this is happening?

Below is my apache conf

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
ServerName repo.example.com:80
NameVirtualHost xx.2xx.xx4.40:80
```

Here is the [verbose of playbook task](https://pastebin.com/raw/10YeSwN5)

Here is the [playbook](https://pastebin.com/a2vJtgHh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The get_url should be pointing to source file path instead of only the website name.

Also the source file should be accessible and downloadable at the first place outside of ansible.

You may refer sample code below if you want:

https://github.com/rbgithuub/devopsdemo/blob/master/ansible_roles/jdk/tasks/main.yml

Comment: Thanks it worked , in combination that i placed the  website.tgz file in DocumentRoot directory with extra directories in between. That is as/var/www/html/website.tgz and not as /var/www/html/repo.example.com/website.tgz